# Window size cut off with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

My window is being cut down to 1/4th its size. The actual window is the correct size, but everything in it is contained in a small box in the center. What is wrong?

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

#problematic portion
w = Canvas(window)
window.geometry("800x800")

w.pack()
w.create_oval(0, 0, 800, 800, fill="#476042")
mainloop()
```

It works when I change the problematic lines to a single line with

```
w = Canvas(window, width=800, height=800)
```

but because of the project I am doing, I can not change those two lines. I can only add to these lines. Any advice?

Comment: Are you aware that `pack` has many options, including options to expand to fill a window?

Comment: I am not! I've actually never made GUIs before and just had this project thrown on me. I will have to look up everything pack can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default canvas size is smaller then the window. You need to adjust the size using the `config` method.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

#problematic portion
w = Canvas(window)
window.geometry("800x800")
w.config(height=800,width=800)  # fill screen

w.create_oval(0, 0, 800, 800, fill="#476042")
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

Output

[image: Oval]

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you!